# Windows beeps when I type the n in account or mount

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

This is a weird issue, I've got a Lenovo laptop running Windows 7 Enterprise. Whenever I type the word mount or account as I hit the n it beeps.

I've tried other similar words, sprout, tout etc but they don't trigger the beep.

When I was running Linux on the machine I noticed that occasionally the n wouldn't appear when I typed it. I assumed this was due to me not hitting the key in the right way to trigger it but I guess it could be the same issue as it was usually when I was typing mount that I noticed it.

No other keys are stuck and it is doing it in various apps so not just one particular one. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: I know very unlikely, but, has number lock has been pressed? To turn off the number lock press and hold down the shift key and press the NumLk/ScrLk key? It sounds like the n is not 'faulting' (hardware) but sending a command which isn't recognised (like N = New File).

Comment: That was my first thought, too. Maybe a modifier key (e.g. Alt or Fn) is faulty / stuck? Does the problem still show when using an external USB keyboard? Strange that only certain words trigger it...